# wordpress permalink structure not changing on multisite on subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a wordpress site running multistage on sub directories.

when changing the permalink structure on the main site everything goes ok,
and site displays the posts/pages on /%postname%/ structure.

But when im making the same change on the subdirecoty blog the structure stays the same
/%category%/%postname%/ it ignores my changes.

Need to know how i can fix that...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that pages are automatically getting the parent page on the %postname%
fixed that using a plugin called ["custom permalinks"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/)

its a shame that WordPress doesn't have a built-in option for that ...